# Cordova Content Security Policy

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-cordova, content-security-policy

I have a Cordova app and after upgrading (5.0.0) it I'm unable to call any resource at all. I've added the whitelist plugin and added the following tag to index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.azure-mobile.net localhost:1337 *.ajax.aspnetcdn.com">
```

I got the following errors:

> Refused to load the script 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.5.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:  "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.azure-mobile.net localhost:1337 *.ajax.aspnetcdn.com".
>
> Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:1337/vorlon.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.azure-mobile.net localhost:1337 *.ajax.aspnetcdn.com".

I've tried with the default policy that should allow everything, but still no luck.

I've also added the following to my config.xml file

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

and using the following plugins:

```
C:\Projects\TavlaApp>cordova plugin
com.microsoft.azure-mobile-services 1.2.7 "Windows Azure Mobile Services"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.1-dev "Whitelist"
nl.x-services.plugins.calendar 4.3.4 "Calendar"
nl.x-services.plugins.insomnia 4.0.1 "Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"
```

Any idea's what to try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like there was something wrong with my plugin/platform.

I did a remove of all plugins

```
   cordova platform rm android
   cordova platform add android
```

Then readded the plugins, and everything works.

Comment: Cordova 5.0 seems to have changed a lot. Particularly for Android, where they've switched fully to gradle based builds, instead of ANT. I've encountered a few 3rd party plugins that no longer compile, referencing non-existent function calls.

Answer (score 30):

Wildcards are accepted, but only as a scheme, a port, or in the leftmost position of the hostname:

```
*://*.example.com:*
```

...this would match all subdomains of example.com (**but not example.com itself**), using any scheme, on any port.

The key here, for you, might be the part in **bold** above.

You're specifying:

```
localhost:1337

*.ajax.aspnetcdn.com
```

But yet calling

```
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com

http://localhost:1337
```

Maybe change to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.azure-mobile.net http://localhost:1337 http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com">
```

I'm specifying port, but you could replace "http" with *

Hopefully this helps, or leads you in right direction.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for looking into this. Your answer did not fix the issue, but I got it resolved removing and adding the plugins.

Comment: Looked at so many examples this is the only one that worked.. cheers !

Comment: Thanks, It works in my cordova project.  I replaced the meta in my html file with this <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.azure-mobile.net http://localhost:1337 http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com">

Comment: Excellent, when I put the url(host+port+context) in the tag meta its works for me too!!!

Comment: I got an "invalid source" error in Chrome debugger when trying a wildcard as the scheme, i.e., `*://192.168.2.2`

Comment: I confirmed my error - you cannot use a wildcard in the scheme.  [See the spec here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#source-list-syntax)

Answer (score -4):

I got this issue while trying to install cordova-plugins-whitelist for Cordova 5. Here is the install log:

Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

```
This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.
```

As we can see, this plugin is no longer necessary in Cordova v5!!

Comment: Isn't it the opposite? You do need it for >= v4?