# Ionic: Refused to load the script

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am trying to post data to this API - http://115.114.95.123:9443/sites/quickcart/api/store/list

When I do this am getting the following error.

> Refused to load the script 'http://10.1.7.155:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".

Even when i hit google api then also i am getting the same error.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/api-key
```

This is my meta data

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Can someone explain me clearly what I should change in meta data?
I am a beginner in Ionic.

Comment: Does this answer solve our problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30199140/3337164

Comment: @Bharat No it is not working